# How do I close the other modal dialog box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following example http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/Mz9QU/1/

If you click on Link2 and then Link1 I want Link2 box to close.

Can anyone help?

Comment: There's something quite poetic about the phrase "the other modal dialog"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I forked your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vHHQr/1/)

The fix just involves calling your `close_model()` function before the `show_modal()` function to close any other open modals before opening the new one :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just call `close_modal();` as soon as any modal box is opened? This would hide any open dialog/modal boxes whether they're open or not but would create minimal overhead (probably less than putting a check to see if any are open).